# Uniquely identify device?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

While visiting Hulu's website, I encountered this message from the browser:

[image]

I have never seen this before. Is this part of some new HTML5 API that everyone can use, or is it part of a vendor specific API, ie `chrome.*`? I don't think this is doable before but the HTML5 spec might have changed.

Comment: according to https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10636413 it's Chrome for Android only: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4410268?p=mobile_protected_content&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the playback of DRM media which is encrypted. There is an article [here](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/html5-video-at-netflix-721d1f143979) on how Netflix rolled out their protected playback for browsers.
Google has their own open source library called [Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) which would allow you to implement your own DRM media solution. You might be interested in the available underlying web APIs which makes this possible in the browser by looking under Media [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).
And of course, you can control which sites are allowed to ID your device and play protected content by visiting [this page](http://chrome://settings/content) in your Chrome config and looking under Protected Content.